# How to put an invisible marker on a model and refer to it in the game?

Tags: xna, c#, 3dsmax, fbx

I am using XNA/C# to load up 3ds Max models exported in FBX format. Is there some way to mark a specific point in the model like the pipe of a gun so I can just refer to it and place a bullet in there directly to make shooting look good?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with XNA specifically but most 3D development tools allow you to refer to bones in the model. In 3ds max just put a bone in the gun and then refer to that bone's position in your code.

Comment: I can confirm that this his how Unreal (at least the UDK) has been able to handle such things.

Comment: All the packages I know of allow you to look up both raw and transformed bones by name.  Most packages have a lightweight bone or node attached to a bone specifically for this purpose.  There must be an example in XNA on finding a bone/node in an XNA model.